# Using a pod without using the node ip

Tags: kubernetes

I have a postgres pod running locally on a coreOS vm.
I am able to access postgres using the ip of the minion it is on but I'm attempting to set it up in such a manner as to not have to know exactly which minion the pod is on but still be able to use postgres.

Here is my pod

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: postgresql
  labels:
    role: postgres-client
spec:
  containers:
  - image: postgres:latest
    name: postgres
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5432
      hostPort: 5432
      name: pg-port
    volumeMounts:
      - name: nfs
        mountPath: /mnt
  volumes:
    - name: nfs
      nfs:
       server: nfs.server
       path: /
```

and here is a service I tried to set-up but it doesn't seem correct

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: postgres-client
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5432
      targetPort: 5432
  selector:
    app: postgres-client
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that the selector for your service is not finding any matching backends.

Try changing

```
app: postgres-client
```

to

```
role: postgres-client
```

in the service definition (or vice versa in the pod definition above).

The label selector has to match both the key and value (i.e. `role` and `postgres-client`). See the [Labels](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/user-guide/labels.md) doc for more details.

Comment: I was able to connect to my service using the endpoint.  Is it possible to define what ip the endpoint gets?

Comment: Not right now. A pod's IP is chosen by docker from the CIDR range allocated to the node that pod is scheduled on.